# Python ctypes copy structure located in temporary buffer

Tags: python, copy, ctypes

I have a code that looks like this:

```py
from ctypes import *
some_library = CDLL('/usr/lib/black_box.so')

# This `Group` comes from `some_library`
class Group(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("ChSize", c_uint32*9),
        ("DataChannel", POINTER(c_float)*9),
        ("TriggerTimeLag", c_uint32),
        ("StartIndexCell", c_uint16)]

class Thing(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("A", c_uint8*4),
        ("B", Group*4)]

pointer_to_thing = POINTER(Thing)()

def get_things():
    some_library.allocate_memory()
    some_library.read_things()
    things = []
    for n in range(some_library.how_many_things_did_your_read()):
        some_library.decode_next_thing()
        pointer_to_thing = some_library.give_me_the_thing()
        thing = pointer_to_thing.contents
        things.append(thing)
    some_library.release_memory()
    return things

things = get_things()
```

which fails because `some_library.give_me_the_thing()` is giving me a reference to the thing and `some_library.release_memory()` is releasing the memory where the thing is. If I comment `some_library.release_memory()` it works, but it is not how it is supposed to be done. I must release the memory before returning from my function, so I would like to make a copy of the thing and return this copy, like this:

```py
def get_things():
    some_library.allocate_memory()
    some_library.read_things()
    things = []
    for n in range(some_library.how_many_things_did_your_read()):
        some_library.decode_next_thing()
        pointer_to_thing = some_library.give_me_the_thing()
        thing = pointer_to_thing.contents
        copy_of_thing = Thing()
        memmove(
            addressof(copy_of_thing),
            addressof(thing),
            sizeof(Thing),
        )
        things.append(copy_of_thing)
    some_library.release_memory()
    return things
```

However, it always returns a `Thing` with not the correct data. If `some_library.release_memory()` is commented, then it works as expected. It's like it is not copying the contents at all...

I have also tried

```py
def get_things():
    some_library.allocate_memory()
    some_library.read_things()
    things = []
    for n in range(some_library.how_many_things_did_your_read()):
        some_library.decode_next_thing()
        pointer_to_thing = some_library.give_me_the_thing()
        thing = pointer_to_thing.contents
        copy_of_thing = Thing.copy_from_buffer(thing)
        things.append(copy_of_thing)
    some_library.release_memory()
    return things
```

and the behavior is exactly the same, i.e. if I release the memory it fails, if I don't it works.

Unfortunately `some_library` is a complicated black box and I cannot easily create a MWE to post here.

One detail, that may be relevant, is that if I insert the following `print`s:

```py
def get_things():
    some_library.allocate_memory()
    some_library.read_things()
    things = []
    for n in range(some_library.how_many_things_did_your_read()):
        some_library.decode_next_thing()
        pointer_to_thing = some_library.give_me_the_thing()
        thing = pointer_to_thing.contents
        copy_of_thing = Thing.copy_from_buffer(thing)
        print(thing, 'original')
        print(copy_of_thing, 'copy')
        print('-----------')
        things.append(copy_of_thing)
    some_library.release_memory()
    return things
```

I get this:

```
<Thing object at 0x7f8d6f027840> original
<Thing object at 0x7f8d6f0278c0> copy
--------
<Thing object at 0x7f8d6f027940> original
<Thing object at 0x7f8d6f027840> copy
--------
<Thing object at 0x7f8d6f0279c0> original
<Thing object at 0x7f8d6f027940> copy
--------
```

and I see it is placing the copies in memory addresses from the original things, which (I guess) should be in the memory that is handled by `some_library`, thus when it is released, the copies are also destroyed and thus I get empty objects?

Comment: Which data is incorrect? What is *Group* (does it contain pointers)? Probably unrelated, but check [\[SO\]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546).

Comment: @CristiFati I added the definition of `Group`, and yes, it contains pointers. Probably pointing to the buffer that is released, which may be the reason of the failure actually.

Comment: @user171780 Yes, that is for sure your problem. It appears the library wants you to deal with the object in a streamed manner instead of creating copies. Are you sure you want to create copies? Either way, you will need to essentially do a deepcopy, i.e. Copy the contents of the pointers recursively. Writing the correct code for that requires precise knowledge about the library, which you haven't shown, meaning that it's hard to answer this question without documentation of Group and Thing

Comment: What do you want to do with the things returned by the function? Maybe your whole design is wrong, making this question an *XY Problem*.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your object is contiguous memory and doesn't contain pointers to other allocated memory, `.from_buffer_copy()` should work, but then again `.memmove()` should have worked as well.  A simple demo:

```py
import ctypes as ct

crt = ct.CDLL('msvcrt')
crt.malloc.argtypes = ct.c_size_t,
crt.malloc.restype = ct.c_void_p
crt.free.argtypes = ct.c_void_p,
crt.free.restype = None

class Thing(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('a', ct.c_uint8 * 4),
                ('b', ct.c_uint8 * 4))
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Thing(a={bytes(self.a)}, b={bytes(self.b)})'

# A "C" malloc and init of some memory and
# build a thing simulating returning a
# malloc-ed object from C
s = crt.malloc(8)
ct.memmove(s, b'1234abcd', 8)
pthing1 = ct.pointer(Thing.from_address(s)) # C Thing*
print(pthing1, pthing1.contents)

thing2 = Thing.from_buffer(pthing1.contents)  # reference same memory

# OP method, but note the pointer (pthing1) is used directly
thing3 = Thing()
ct.memmove(ct.addressof(thing3), pthing1, ct.sizeof(Thing))

# Simpler method
thing4 = Thing.from_buffer_copy(pthing1.contents)  # make a copy

# fill the thing1 memory with a deleted pattern, then free it.
ct.memmove(s, b'\xdd' * 8, 8)
crt.free(s)
del pthing1

print(thing2)  # still referencing freed memory
print(thing3)  # memmove works
print(thing4)  # from_buffer_copy works
```

Output:

```
<__main__.LP_Thing object at 0x000001C7CCF59850> Thing(a=b'1234', b=b'abcd')
Thing(a=b'\xdd\xdd\xdd\xdd', b=b'\xdd\xdd\xdd\xdd')
Thing(a=b'1234', b=b'abcd')
Thing(a=b'1234', b=b'abcd')
```

Comment: After your comment about the contiguous memory, I decided to check on that. I slightly modified the body of the question, which includes a `for` loop that I originally omitted for the sake of simplicity, but now I realize it may be relevant. It seems to be placing the copies of the things inside the memory buffer that is handled by `some_library`.